Office Script to format raw data and export to csv
I am new with Office Scripts. Here is what I am trying to accomplish

If A9 is 1, copy Raw_Data sheet F9 to J9 to temp sheet A1 to E1
If A10 is 2, copy Raw_Data E10 and I10 to temp sheet F1 and G1
If A11 is 2, copy Raw_Data sheet F9 to J9 to temp sheet A2 to E2 and copy Raw_Data E11 and I11 to temp sheet F2 and G2
If A12 is 2, copy Raw_Data sheet F9 to J9 to temp sheet A3 to E3 and copy Raw_Data E12 and I12 to temp sheet F3 and G3
If A13 is 1, copy Raw_Data sheet F13 to J13 to temp sheet A4 to E4
If A14 is 2, copy Raw_Data E14 and I14 to temp sheet F4 and G4
If A15 is 2, copy Raw_Data sheet F15 to J15 to temp sheet A5 to E5 and copy Raw_Data E15 and I15 to temp sheet F5 and G5



Here is Raw_Data sheet




A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L




1
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
CUSTOMER
SHIPTO
TYPE
ORDDATE
EXPDATE
PONUMBER
LOCATION
REQUESDATE




2
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
LINENUM
LINETYPE
ITEM
_MISCCHARG
_PRICELIST
_LOCATION
QTYORDERED
_PRIUNTPRC
_ORDUNIT
_EXTINVMIS


3
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
LINENUM
SERIALNUMF
DETAILNUM
MOVED
QTY
QTYMOVED






4
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
LINENUM
LOTNUMF
DETAILNUM
EXPIRYDATE
STKQTY
QTY
STKQTYMOVE
QTYMOVED




5
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
PAYMENT
DISCBASE
DISCDATE
DISCPER
DISCAMT
DUEBASE
DUEDATE
DUEPER
DUEAMT



6
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
UNIQUIFIER
DETAILNUM
COINTYPE
COIN








7
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
OPTFIELD
VALUE










8
RECTYPE
ORDUNIQ
LINENUM
OPTFIELD










9
1
1
WAFHOM
88888
1
20240610
20240801
2462460
USA
20240806




10
2
1
1
1
ANT1



2
0




11
2
1
1
1
ANT2



4
0




12
2
1
1
1
ANT3



1
0




13
1
1
WAFHOM
999999
1
20240610
20240801
2462460
CAN
20240806




14
2
1
1
1
PINA1



4
0





Here is the output sheet




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
20240610
20240801
2462460
USA
20240806
ANT1
2


2
20240610
20240801
2462460
USA
20240807
ANT2
4


3
20240610
20240801
2462460
USA
20240808
ANT3
1


4
20240610
20240801
2462460
CAN
20240806
PINA1
4



Here is what I've tried to come up with which is not much
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let test_row = 9;
    let test_column = 1;
    let test_empty = 0;
    
    const sheet_temp = workbook.getWorksheet("Temp");
    const sheet_raw = workbook.getWorksheet("Raw_Data");
    const sheet_Upload = workbook.getWorksheet("Upload_SO_Xorosoft");

    while (test_empty == 0) {
        if (sheet_temp.getCell(test_row, test_column).getValue() == 1) {
            //this to test if A9=1
            ;
        }
        else if (sheet_temp.getCell(test_row, test_column).getValue() == 2) {
            //this to test if A9=2
            ;
        }
        else {
            //this to test if A9 is blank
            //complete do while condition
            test_empty=1;
        }
         //export to csv
    }
}


And what is your question?  Does the code work?  What happens or doesn't happen?

Sorry for not being clearer. No, this code does not work. the code does not go inside the if conditions, and I tried to test with console but couldn't get the .getValue() to show on console.log

The data extraction logic can be simplified as follows:

If a cell in Column A is 1, then retrieve 5 columns (Columns A to E in the output table).
If a cell in Column B is 2, then retrieve 2 columns (Columns F and G in the output table).



Load data into array dataValues
Populate output array resRows
Write output to sheet

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const startRow = 9;
    const colCnt = 10;
    const sheet_temp = workbook.getWorksheet("Temp");
    const sheet_raw = workbook.getWorksheet("Raw_Data");
    const lastRow = sheet_raw.getRange("A:A").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getRowIndex();
    const dataValues = sheet_raw.getRangeByIndexes(startRow - 1, 0, lastRow - startRow + 2, colCnt).getValues();
    let resRows: [] = [];
    let dataRow: [] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        if (dataValues[i][0] == "1") {
            dataRow = [];
            for (let j = 5; j < dataValues[0].length; j++) {
                dataRow.push(dataValues[i][j]);
            }
        }
        else if (dataValues[i][0] == "2") {
            let newRow: [] = [...dataRow];
            newRow.push(dataValues[i][4]);
            newRow.push(dataValues[i][8]);
            // console.log(newRow)
            resRows.push(newRow)
        }
    }
    let useRange = sheet_temp.getUsedRange();
    if(useRange){ useRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);}
    sheet_temp.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, resRows.length, resRows[0].length).setValues(resRows);
}


Note:

OfficeScripts cannot export a sheet to CSV like VBA can. However, you can accomplish this using Power Automate.


Save XLSX Excel all worksheets as csv


This looks awesome. I'll take time to digest this. too bad office scripting does not have debug tools like VBA yet. But Thank you. I will try this out.

This works. Thank you so much. Where do I learn Office Scripting other than Youtube and Microsoft Documentation? I am looking to do API with Office Scripts also.

The samples are pretty good. Microsoft documentation:

Office Scripts samples and scenarios

